# OCaml syntax error on filter

Tags: recursion, syntax-error, ocaml

I just begin OCaml (and functional programming) today and I'm trying to code a function that count the number of occurrences of "value" into an array (tab).
I tried :

```
let rec count_occ tab value =
    let rec count_rec idx time = function
        | tab.length - 1 -> time
        | _ when tab.(indice) == value-> count_rec (idx + 1) (time + 1)
        | _ -> count_rec (indice + 1) time
    in
    count_rec 0 0
;;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile because of a syntax error, and I don't find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let rec count_occ tab value =
```

This rec above is not necessary.

```
    let rec count_rec idx time = function
        | tab.length - 1 -> time
```

You cannot match against an expression. You want to use guards like you did on the next line, or `if` statements to test something like this. `tab.length` also does not exist as `tab` is an `array`, not a record with a `length` field. You want `Array.length tab`.

Really though, you don't want the `function` at all. `function` is the same as `fun x -> match x with`, and would imply that `count_rec` has type, `int -> int -> int -> int`.

```
        | _ when tab.(indice) == value-> count_rec (idx + 1) (time + 1)
```

`indices` is not declared; lets assume you meant idx. Also, `==` is physical equality, you really want `=`.

```
        | _ -> count_rec (indice + 1) time
    in
    count_rec 0 0
```

You're off to a good start, the basics of your recursion are correct although one edge case is incorrect, but a minor issue you should be able to resolve once you have the syntactic issues fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on the right way now, my code look at : http://pastie.org/8746861 But it's doesn't really works

Comment: when you do your `match idx with | n` you are creating a new binding of `idx` to `n`, not testing that the contents of `n` are equal to `idx`. This is done in a guard instead. Matching is structural, as in decomposing lists and tuples and matching against variants and constants.

Comment: Once you fix that, you should instantly notice that matching isn't appropriate in this case --you'll be matching with `_` in all three cases. Use if statements instead.

Comment: What you've conflated about pattern matching is a very common mistake.

Answer (score 1):

finnaly I post my final code :

```
let count_occ tab value =
    let rec count_rec idx time =
        if (Array.length tab) = idx then
            time
        else if (tab.(idx)) = value then
            count_rec (idx + 1) (time + 1)
        else
            count_rec (idx + 1) time
    in
    count_rec 0 0
;;
```

Comment: looks good! the extra parenthesis around `tab.(idx)` and doing `idx = Array.length tab` can save you _precious_ keystrokes ;).